# Purpose of Reference to a Constructor : Java 8

Tags: java, method-reference

I was going through documentation of [Method References in Java8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

in which  i encountered a table about kinds of Method Reference , Out of 4 the last one

```
-----------------------------------------------
Reference to a constructor :    ClassName::new 
-----------------------------------------------
```

> You can reference a constructor in the same way as a static method by
>   using the name new.

I am unable to understand What exactly does **Reference to a constructor do** ?

**Note :** I know Java Documentation is self explanatory but in this case i'm failing to understand what exactly it wants to convey .

Comment: Does this help: http://www.speakingcs.com/2014/08/constructor-references-in-java-8.html ?

Answer (score 0):

It allows some generic code to instantiate objects of the type for which you pass the constructor.

So if you pass in a `SomeClass::new` to a function `f` like

```
f(SomeClass::new)
```

the function `f` then is able to create instances of the `SomeClass` type.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor reference can be used whenever you call a method that requires a supplier (i.e. it has a parameter whose type is `Supplier<T>`). The constructor of class T can serve as a `Supplier<T>`.

So, for example, consider this example taken from the Javadoc of the Collectors class:

```
Set<String> set = 
    people.stream()
          .map(Person::getName)
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

`Collectors.toCollection` requires a `Supplier`. When you pass to it a constructor of `TreeSet` - `TreeSet::new` - it will use is to create a `TreeSet` instance that would contain the elements of the Stream. If you pass to it a `HashSet::new`, it would create a `HashSet` instance instead of the `TreeSet`.

Comment: How it will stand in case of **Constructor Overloading** ??

Comment: @NeerajJain The typical use case of using constructor references uses the parameterless constructor (in my example, the `get()` method of `Supplier` has no parameters), but I think it's possible to use it with other constructors. For example, you might process a `List<String>` like this : `List<MyClass> mylist = list.stream().map(MyClass::new).collect(Collectors.toList())`. This will transform a `List<String>` to a `List<MyClass>` using `MyClass`'s constructor having a single String argument.

Comment: @NeerajJain It won't be a problem for method overload, as the parameter list is not of the same length. In a case, where the required function has more than one parameter - and of the same formal types - it will be _that_ construcor that will be called.